# Period finding for amplitude encoding of function

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform, period-finding-algorithm

In quantum Fourier transform, amplitude encoding is used to represent function $f(x)$ such that $|\psi\rangle = \sum_x f(x)|x\rangle$, with $f(x)$ being amplitude. In Shor's algorithm, it is not this version that is used for period finding of $f(x)$. Is there a known quantum algorithm for period-finding of $f(x)$ based on $|\psi\rangle$, whenever only copies of $|\psi\rangle$ are available, without means to classically compute $f(x)$?

Comment: Did you mean to say "period-finding of $f(x)$?

Comment: @rhundt Yes, and I edited the question.